# Reading a lot of files in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm looking to read some files ( each file is about 2MB ).

At first I tried :

```
    for (var j = 0; j <= limit2; ++j)
    fs.readFile(base + i * j + last, {encoding: "utf-8"}, function (err, data) {
        cnt++;
        if (cnt == limit2)
            console.timeEnd("random");
    });
```

This does a good job but it seems the reading time is not liniar forever :

```
30 files : ~8s
300 files : ~ 12s
600 files : ~ 22s
1000 files : ~ 120s
```

Therefore, my idea was to read those file in chucks. What I mean by this is : start reading like 10 files, wait for all of them to complete and just then proceed with the next 10 files and so on.

I've tried doing something alike this :

```
function ReadFiles() {
for (var j = 0; j <= limit2; ++j)
    fs.readFile(base + i * j + last, {encoding: "utf-8"}, function (err, data) {
        cnt++;
        if (cnt == limit2)
           // console.timeEnd("random");
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i <= limit1; ++i) {
GoOn = false;
cnt = 0;
ReadFiles();
}
console.timeEnd("random");
```

How should I make the for loop pause until the ReadFile function is done?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the async module a try.
It has a special `.queue` method for exactly this usecase :
https://github.com/caolan/async#queue

Otherwise it should not be so complicated to implement this by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use Promises, I especially like **[bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)** because it has some very handy functionality.

With bluebird, you can supply a `concurrency` parameter to the `.map()` function, to limit the number of files read at once. Rather than waiting for 10 files to complete, then chunking another 10, it would just make sure that no more than 10 files are read simulataneously:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = require('fs');

// Creates a promise returning function from a callback-based function
var readFileAsync = Promise.promisify(fs.readFile);

// Add all filenames into an array
var files = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= limit1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; i <= limit2; j++) {
        files.push(base + i*j + last); 
    }
}

var allDonePromise = Promise.map(files, function(file) {
    return readFileAsync(file, {encoding: "utf-8"});
}, { concurrency: 10 }); // Magic is here!
allDonePromise.then(function(allFileContents) {
    // Here, we're all done!
});
```

Comment: Kinda runs out of memory :P

Comment: @user1640736 I have a similar construct over 100,000 files, and I don't run out of memory. What version of node are you running, and on what server?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a memory problem, happens with 1 file also : http://paste.isomorphis.me/W0n

Comment: Sorry, copy-pasted your code, you have i <= limit2 instead of j. At 1000 files I run out of memory.

Comment: @user1640736 I merely repeated the general setup you have. It's also not a very good one (relying on the multiplication of numbers to generate file names), but that's your business, not mine :P

Comment: I like your idea, looks good, not really good when having to keep thousands of filenames in an array :P takes up a lot of memory :(

Comment: @user1640736: Really? Each filename is what, 50 bytes? 5000 files would be 250kB of memory plus a few bytes overhead? I'd be more worried about the contents of said thousands of files.